# Session are not maintained for new request in django when using iframe

Tags: django, python-3.x, session, chatbot

I am creating a chatbot. for that i am maintaining session to create chat flow. and its working properly when running the server. But when i am using iframe to give link of the file of chat window then session are not maintained. for every new request older session got destroyed.

this is my code for the chat flow

```
def extract_data(request, input_data):
        from chat import validations
        if 'city' not in request.session:
            response_data = {'extra': {}, 'data': {}}
            response_data['extra']['statement'] = 'Select Car Model which you like to rent?'
            response_data['extra']['type'] = 'carmodel'
            response_data['data'] = Cars.city_check(request,response_data, input_data)

        elif 'veh_name' not in request.session:
            response_data = Cars.veh_name_check(request, input_data)

        elif 'days' not in request.session:
            response_data = validations.days_check(request, input_data)

        elif 'phone' not in request.session:
            response_data = validations.phone_check(request, input_data)

        elif 'email' not in request.session:
            response_data = validations.mail_check(request, input_data)

        elif 'name' not in request.session:
            response_data = validations.name_check(request, input_data, 'Car')

        return response_data




def city_check(request, response_data, input_data):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        if len(input_data.split()) == 6:
            request.session['city'] = input_data.split()[4]+' '+input_data.split()[5]
        else:request.session['city'] = input_data.split()[4]
        request.session['flag'] = 0
        city_list = dict(city=list(models.CityForCars.objects.filter(CityForCars=request.session['city']).values_list().values().order_by('id')))

        city = city_list['city'][0]['id']
        car_model_data = dict(car_model=list(models.CarModel.objects.filter(City_id=city).values_list().values().order_by('id')))

        response_data = car_model_data    
        return response_data

    @staticmethod
    def veh_name_check(request, input_data):
        response_data = {'extra': {}, 'data': {}}
        response_data['extra']['statement'] = 'For how many days are you looking to rent a vehicle? (Type or tap below)'
        response_data['data'] = ['1 Day', '2 Day', '3 Day', '4 Day', '5+ Days']
        response_data['extra']['type'] = 'duration'
        diff=' '
        request.session['veh_name'] = diff.join(input_data.split()[5:])
        return response_data

    @staticmethod
    def customer_details(request, data, client_ip):
        serializer = CustomerDetailPage(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            profile = serializer.save()
            print('data completely saved')
            print('client ipppppppppppppppppppppppppp')
            print(client_ip)
            common.send_mail(profile, client_ip)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=200)
        return HttpResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

    @staticmethod
    def car_selected(request, input_text):
        request.session['car_selected'] = 1
        request.session['car_flag'] = 1
        print(request.session)

    @staticmethod
    def check_car_city(request, input_text):
        for input in input_text.split():
            if models.CityForCars.objects.filter(CityForCars=input.title()).values().exists():
                print(input)
                return input
            else:
                return None

    @staticmethod
    def vehicle_city(request, vehicle):
        if vehicle == 'cars':
            if request.session['count_flag'] == 1:
                request.session['end_count'] = 5
                request.session['start_count'] = 0
                request.session['count_flag'] = 0

            car_city = dict(city=list(models.CityForCars.objects.values_list().values().order_by('id')[
                                      request.session['start_count']:request.session['end_count']]))
            request.session['start_count'] = 5 + request.session['start_count']
            request.session['end_count'] = 5 + request.session['end_count']
            if len(car_city['city']) == 5:
                car_city['city'].append({'id': 10000, 'CityForCars': 'more...'})
            return car_city

    @staticmethod
    def car_models(request, city):
        car_model_data = dict(
            city=list(models.CarModel.objects.filter(City_id=city).values_list().values().order_by('id')))


def book_vehicle(request, input_data):
    serializer = BookVehicleSerializer(data=input_data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        print('data completely saved')
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=200)
    return HttpResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)


def fetch_cars_models(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        input_data = json.loads(request.read().decode('utf-8'))
        if models.CarModel.objects.filter(City_id=input_data['city_id']):
            car_city = dict(cars=list(models.CarModel.objects.filter(City_id=input_data['city_id']).values_list().values().order_by('id')))
            return JsonResponse(car_city, status=200)
        return HttpResponse('error', status=400)


def fetch_bikes_models(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        input_data = json.loads(request.read().decode('utf-8'))
        if models.BikeModel.objects.filter(City_id=input_data['city_id']):
            car_city = dict(bikes=list(models.BikeModel.objects.filter(City_id=input_data['city_id']).values_list().values().order_by('id')))
            return JsonResponse(car_city, status=200)
        return HttpResponse('error', status=400)
```

i created a new folder in which i provide the front end of the project. and gives the base url. but when i am using iframe and provide the link of that file. it does not maintaining sessions. please help me to resolve this issue.